# Spring Boot route/path configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm experiencing a little struggle with the route configuration. Here is my setup:

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/MyApp
```

**IndexController.java**

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {


  @GetMapping(path = "/")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getHelloWorld() {...}
}
```

**SomethingAController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/api")
public class SomethingAController {


  @GetMapping(path = "somethingA/all")
  public ResponseEntity<List<SomthingA>> getAll() {...}
  .
  .
  .
}
```

**SomethingBController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest/api")
public class SomethingBController {


  @GetMapping(path = "somethingB/all")
  public ResponseEntity<List<SomthingB>> getAll() {...}
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Soo.. what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

- `/MyApp`

  > Simply returns "Hello World" (In a real world scenario there would be something a bit more sophisticated)
- `/MyApp/rest/api/somethingA/all`

  > Returns the results of the SomethingAController getAll().
- `/MyApp/rest/api/somethingB/all`

  > Returns the results of the SomethingBController getAll().

I've tried a few things.

Initially, I had the `server.servlet.context-path` set to `/MyApp/rest/api` and the `@RequestMapping` just set to `/`, which was working fine, but then there is no way of returning anything under just `/MyApp`.

To be able to make use of `/MyApp`, I came up the setup which is described above, but for some reason this results in that the endpoints are not responding anymore. I'm still getting `200`s back, but with no data.

After some playing around, I figured out that if I just set the `@RequestMapping` of the `SomethingAController` and `SomethingBController` to `/rest` or to `/api` that seems be working.

Whilst it is nice that it is working the setting the `@RequestMapping` to either `/rest` or to `/api`, I'd like to configure it to `/rest/api`. This is not because that I think it is better, but rather to maintain an already existing REST interface.

Using:

- spring-boot: 2.1.7.RELEASE
- jdk: 11

Comment: What exactly is going wrong / what errors are you getting with the code you posted above?

Comment: It’s not coming back with anything. Even the server response comes back with a 200, but with no data at all.

Answer (score 1):

try to use value instead of path

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
```

or

```
 @RequestMapping("/hello")
```

and for

specify the method

```
 @GetMapping(value = "somethingB/all")
  public ResponseEntity<List<SomthingB>> getAll() {...}
  .
  .
  .
}
```

if the problem persists clean your project.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value="/rest")` works, but using `@RequestMapping(value="/rest/api")` doesn't. Also `@GetMapping` already implements `RequestMethod.GET`.

Comment: which error do you get? And maybe you need to post the code too

Comment: None, that is the frustrating things. Swagger cognises my endpoints, but when doing a request it comes back with a `200` and an empty body.

Comment: try something like `@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/api", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: Ha, found it. I've a `FilterRegistrationBean`, to filter out http requests and to log them. Something wasn't properly configured there, which seems to have caused this strange behaviour. Interesting, this kind of strange and to difficult to connect these two dots.

Comment: I do understand, congs a lot !